# How to change euler form of complex to trigonometric form.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

In physics, my professor often writes the function $f_{0}\sin(pt)$ as $f_{0}e^{ipt}$.

But I don't understand this, because I know that 
$e^{it}$ = $\cos t + i \sin t$

Please explain why my professor can write it like this.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics, there's a convention to ease calculation of operations on waves by writing $e^{i pt}$ instead of $\cos(pt)$, then implicitly only pay attention to the real part in the answer. It looks like your professor is doing this with the imaginary part instead (or, more likely, he is assuming a phase constant as part of the $f_0$). You should check his work to see if his usage conforms to this idea.